# mp4 file not working on Firefox and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, video, mp4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
</head>

<body>
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="300" height="170" poster="../images/audi/audi_poster.png"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="../videos/audi/audi.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 <source src="../videos/audi/audi.ogg" type='video/ogg'>
 <source src="../videos/audi/audi.webm" type='video/webm'>

 </video>
 </body>
 </html>
```

For the above code, the file plays without any error on Google Chrome but not on Firefox and IE.

I have no idea where I am wrong.. PLease help.. I really need to solve this issue.
pls help

The website runs on goddady server. I am not using any database to store the video file nor any php programming.. I simply upload the video to the server n the the html file...
Its a very simple page I want to have with the video playing for all 3 browsers..

Comment: What is the version of **Mozilla Firefox** and **Internet Explorer** are you using? And moreover, it has to start with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and not with the one that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 `video` and `audio` tag support is not the friendliest at the moment.

Firstly you DOCTYPE should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` as mentioned in the comment. Then there are a couple of things to consider:

1. Firefox doesn't support MP4 playback, neither does Opera. You will need to convert the video from MP4 to WEBM or OGG format and put them in the same directory as the MP4 to suit your example.
2. IE8 and below don't support the `<video>` tag at all and I'm guessing that's the problem with your IE version. IE9 does support MP4 playback however.

After having a good play with this for a project I am currently working on here are some of the issues I also came across:

1. iOS devices (and mobile devices in general) don't really like the tag (especially inline), after playing with it for a while I ended up just straight linking to the MP4 video and it now opens up in the default player.
2. Google Chrome or IE9 don't support a fullscreen button yet, but Safari does. Haven't checked FF or Opera, see below.
3. To avoid the need for users to upload 3 different files. I've added a flash fallback (Flowplayer) for FF and Opera (and any browser that doesn't support MP4 `<video>` playback). I may create the WEBM or OGG files on the server, but this also helps with older browser like IE8. Here is a **JavaScript** snippet on how to check support for MP4 playback:

   ```
   var flashaudioplayer=false;
   var flashvideoplayer=false;

   // Check if browser supports HTML5 native mp3/mp4 playback
   var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
   var videoTag = document.createElement('video');
   if (!(!!(audioTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) && ("" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")))) {
   flashaudioplayer=true;

   }
   if (!(!!(videoTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != videoTag.canPlayType("video/mp4")) && ("" != videoTag.canPlayType("video/mp4")))) {
   flashvideoplayer=true;
   }
   ```
4. You will also find the same issues with MP3 playback support in the `<audio>` tags, Flowplayer also has a way to play MP3 files so it's a nice option for a flash fallback.

Comment: You don't need to detect MP4 support yourself - just add the Flash player _inside_ the `<video>` tag right after the MP4 `<source>`. Browsers that support MP4 will play the video and ignore the rest of the video tag's children, FF/IE9 ignores the MP4 video and plays the Flash version instead and old IE browsers ignore both the video and source tag, seeing only the Flash element.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja I had some problems with this when I was playing with mobile devices. But yes you are correct.

Comment: Even when I haveall 3 formats also, the file is not playing in the FF or IE ??
If I convert to a flash file - audi.swf, will it play in all three browsers